# Using STUFF to combine rows

Tags: sql

This is what I have so far, but it's showing too many results. It's grouping the description row together fine, but it's doing it for each result. I basically want it so there are only 3 rows. One for each class http://prntscr.com/1la4j2

```
    /* 3. List the part number, part description, and item class for each pair of parts that are in the same item
class */
SELECT 
  t1.partnum,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.description 
    FROM part t2
    WHERE t1.class = t2.class
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS description, t1.class
FROM part t1
```

Comment: Not very clear in what you want and you don't really explain it

Comment: "I basically want it so there are only 3 rows. One for each class http://prntscr.com/1la4j2"

Comment: nobody understands you table structure or your data set - so 3 rows does not make sense.

Comment: Why don't you use limit? If I even understand

Comment: The screenshot works, but it's much nicer to have the question stand on it's own without links, so consider adding sample data to future questions.

Comment: @CodyRobinson Your comment link requires me to install an app to view it, so I'm afraid that you lost me right there. (I know that you can't load an image as you haven't got 10 rep, but making people install stuff isn't a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

You could remove t1.partnum from your `SELECT`

Or list Partnum and Description together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' t2.PartNum + '-' + t2.description 
    FROM part t2
    WHERE t1.class = t2.class
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS description, t1.class
FROM part t1
```

Or make the partnum's into a separate list too, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t3.partnum
    FROM part t3
    WHERE t1.class = t3.class
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS partnum
  ,STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.description 
    FROM part t2
    WHERE t1.class = t2.class
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS description
  , t1.class
FROM part t1
```